# Exceptions and error codes in Java

Tags: java

I have a query regarding error handling in java. Suppose for a library there are several error codes. Is it a good practice to have a single exception and include an enum of error codes in side that, for various errors ?

Update: Is it a good practice to have error codes within an exception?

Comment: Make each error its own type, after you catch the error you'll have to figure out what it is with the enum method.

Comment: I would personally opt for a hierarchy of exception types with a common superclass, so you can catch specific ones if you want to or catch all with a single `catch(ParentException e)`

Answer (score 4):

An *error* and an *error code* are two separate things. One defines what happened and the other one identifies the particular source of the error.

The best example of this are DB related exceptions, where a SQL exception includes a code defining the tipe of error that caused it.

Making that code accessible through an enumeration or a field is a design decision. If you have one exception to throw and you add an error code to it, it can be taken as a two-step exception handling:

1. Catch the exception that determines the context of an error

   - Security
   - Database
   - Processing
   - Parsing
   - Invalid operation
2. Check the exception code to determine the source

   - An user doesn't have enough privileges to do what he tried to do
   - Database connection errora
   - Query related issues
   - The system is currently overloaded
   - No managers found for a certain operation

Once you determined the source (code) and you know its context (exception), you can act accordingly. IMHO, a hierarchy is a good approach that can be extended with a code when needed. Just keep in mind that there's an impact in maintainability and complexity if you go as far as to subclass an exception 10 times just to represent the source.

Comment: but the thing is, suppose method A calls method B to get some value. Some error occurs in B. So the best way to flag that error is B throws an exception. But A needs to return an error code to its caller. How to handle this situation?

Comment: You just have to catch the exception in A, and given its context, return the relevant error code to the caller.

Comment: @prashanthkvs Exactly what X.L.Ant said. Another important part of exception handling is the management of their propagation. If the exception is checked and B throws it, A is forced to catch it or throw it. If the exception is an unchecked one, you'll have to be very carful.

Comment: @Gamb So, is it a good practice to store the corresponding error code inside the exception ?

Comment: @prashanthkvs Good practices and Bad Practices are subjective matters. I'd say that massive exception subclassing is a bad practice in terms of maintainability and complexity but I wouldn't use error codes unless necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Not really. You should use different Exception types, one for each error type (within reasonable limits, don't create hundreds of different exception types!).

It allows you to catch only those you really want to catch, instead of processing each exception to discover what happened.

However, feel free to customize exception message to clarify the source of the error inside several exceptions of the same type.

This [simple explanation](http://www.artima.com/interfacedesign/ExceptionType.html) is clear.

Answer (score 2):

The current praxis is having at least one base class (IOException) and child classes like FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException. On the usage side one can then catch all with a IOException.

This allows tackling just FileNotFound.

On the other hand having many codes, like a HTTP response code, your approach of having just one exception is more than justified.

Answer (score 2):

If there are too many error codes, and you don't expect users to catch and recover, it's fine to use one Exception type embedding an integer error code. And you don't really have a choice if the set of error codes cannot be determined at compile time.